# Do I need user 1000, and can I replace it?

Tags: permissions, users, passwd-file

On my computer running Mythbuntu, I'm having a problem where some important processes are being run by a user called `1000`.

```
$ ps -aux | grep myth
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html
avahi     1126  0.0  0.0   3568  1536 ?        S    Jul08   0:02 avahi-daemon: running [mythbuntu.local]
mythtv    1863  0.0  0.8 323960 36096 ?        Sl   Jul08   3:38 /usr/bin/mythbackend --syslog local7 --user mythtv
1000      2278  0.0  0.0   4060   204 ?        Ss   Jul08   0:01 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/share/mythbuntu/session.sh
1000      2281  0.0  0.0   3920   740 ?        S    Jul08   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/share/mythbuntu/session.sh
1000      2336  0.0  0.0   2216   592 ?        S    Jul08   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mythfrontend --service
root      8365  0.0  0.0  10104  3420 ?        Ss   17:40   0:00 sshd: mythbuntu [priv]
1000      8548  0.1  0.0  10252  1772 ?        S    17:40   0:00 sshd: mythbuntu@notty
1000      8624  0.0  0.0   4132   836 pts/3    S+   17:41   0:00 grep --color=auto myth
1000     12749  1.7  6.9 618604 288348 ?       Sl   Jul11 148:53 /usr/bin/mythfrontend.real --syslog local7
```

This seems to be causing other problems with permissions, because processes run by this user can't seem to access commands I need to run from within MythTV and other processes owned by `1000`.

So far as I know, there's only one user on my system that I created, called `mythbuntu`, and my intention was that user run everything. I don't know what this `1000` user is or where it came from.

```
$ grep 1000 /etc/passwd
mythbuntu:x:1000:1000:mythbuntu,,,:/home/mythbuntu:/bin/bash
```

Is this `1000` user important or a default in some way? Or is there a way I can have this `1000"`user essentially removed and anything attributed to that user overtaken by the `mythbuntu` user?

**Note:** this is an extension of an issue I'm trying to resolve on [the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12111660#post12111660).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User ID `1000` is Mythubuntu, your user (notice that the `grep` command was ran by that user when you executed it). The apparent phenomenon is that `ps` does not report user **names** if they are longer than 8 (eight) characters, and subtitutes it with the user **id**.

(*Off:* The proper syntax is `ps aux`, not `ps -aux` (no need for the hyphen). Note the output throws an error on it too.)

#### Edit

To show an example:

```
whisperity@Aspire-5315:/tmp$ ls -l | grep DaveMG
drwxr-xr-x  2 whisperity whisperity     4096 2012-07-18 12:20 DaveMG
```

Clearly, my user has rights to write the folder. I can write into it:

```
whisperity@Aspire-5315:/tmp$ echo "hello Dave" > DaveMG/foobar
whisperity@Aspire-5315:/tmp$ ls -l DaveMG
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 whisperity whisperity 11 2012-07-18 12:21 foobar
```

When I look at the process list (let's say I `hexdump` the file), it will show something like this:

```
whisperity@Aspire-5315:/tmp/DaveMG$ ps aux | grep hexdump
1000     13893  0.8  0.0   3912   508 pts/2    S+   12:24   0:00 hexdump /tmp/somebigfile
1000     13895  0.0  0.0   4156   860 pts/3    S+   12:24   0:00 grep --color=auto hexdump
```

Because `whisperity` is more than eight characters (it's nine characters long), `ps` shows my user's ID.

```
whisperity@Aspire-5315:/tmp/DaveMG$ cat /etc/passwd | grep 1000
whisperity:x:1000:1000:Whisperity,,,:/home/whisperity:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Okay then... I guess I'm not have a problem with a mysterious account. At least this has a simple solution :)

Comment: @DaveMG It's not a mysterious account, it's your account. See the edit to my question.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it's not a mysterious account. That's why I said I'm not having a problem with one. I was agreeing with you.